# Angular Template not updating after scope is filtered

Tags: angularjs

**Template**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="object in objects">{{object.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
function Controller($scope, ObjectFilter) {
    $scope.objects = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
    var ids = [1, 3];
    $scope.objects = ObjectFilter($scope.objects, ids);
}
```

**Filter**

```
function ObjectFilter(objects, ids) {
    var out = [];
    for(i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<objects.length; j++) {
            if(objects[j].id === ids[i]) {
                out.push(objects[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

$scope.objects gets filtered but the template doesn't update.
If I try `$scope.$apply()` I get an Error that $apply is already in progress.

Should this not just work? Why not?!

**EDIT:** So this simplified example seems to work but not my actual code!

**EDIT:** I got it to work by combining two controllers. Thanks for the input, helped me find out where the problem wasn't!

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me! Just change "OjectFilter" to "ObjectFilter"

Comment: Fixed the typo. This is a simplified version of my code. Maybe it's an issue with parent / child scopes.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9gb3s7yk/

You forgot to declare your loop variables: `var i`, `var j`

```
for(var i = 0; i < idCollection.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < objs.length; j++) {
        if(objs[j].id === idCollection[i]) {
            out.push(objs[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The fiddle is still working without the declaration of the counter variables.

Comment: No idea why OP's isn't working then.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Filter function out of scope, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Try to define your $scope only ones like this:

```
function Controller($scope, ObjectFilter) {
   //Private variable inside controller:
   var objects = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
   var ids = [1, 3];

   //Define Viewscope:
   $scope.objects = ObjectFilter(objects, ids);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly! Just change "OjectFilter" to "ObjectFilter"